# Is multiprocessing possible on a turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, parallel-computing

I recently created a parallel implementation of the Merge Sort, in which the sorting of several groups was accomplished by different processes, and was wondering if this was theoretically possible on Turing Machine?

Comment: What do you think? Does oes multi-processing require anything that may or may not be available on a TM?  Why would you want to adress that question to begin with?

Comment: You are not supposed to crosspost on several SE sites. This also appears as http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31378/is-multiprocessing-possible-on-a-turing-machine where ther is already an answer.

Comment: parallelism is studied in many different theoretical ways in TCS, there are many models. yes TMs can "simulate" parallelism somewhat like the way real machines do.

Comment: Cross posted because I was informed that my question wasn't suitable for Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange and was redirected here.

Comment: Real machines only simulate parallelism? What if the machine has a dual-core processor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider two variants of this question.

1. Can a Turing machine simulate parallelism?
2. Can a Turing machine simulate parallelism *efficiently*?

The answer for the first question is a resounding affirmative. Just like your own OS simulates threads on a single-core CPU, so a Turing machine can simulate parallelism.

Regarding the more refined second question, it depends on your definition of efficiency. You can probably simulate parallelism with at most a polynomial blow-up in resources (mainly time).

Turing machines are not a good model if you care about concrete efficiency. The more appropriate model is the *RAM machine*. RAM machines can probably simulate parallelism pretty efficiently, though you should not accept a running time any less that the *combined* running times of the individual threads in your parallel solution.